# Invalid Syntax attempting to write Python closure

Tags: python-2.7, closures, syntax-error

I am attempting to write a function (in Python 2.7) which takes an outstanding balance and annual interest rate then returns the min monthly payment to the nearest cent using bisection search  [to solve problem #3](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-4-machine-interpretation-of-a-program/MIT6_00SCS11_ps1.pdf). I am trying to follow DRY principles by writing a function inside the main function which should return a list with the balance after a year and the number of months (the loop should break if balance hits zero or less) which will need to be calculated twice in my main function. As I try to test this initial closure before moving on I am getting a syntax error on the line assigning `monthlyPayment`. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Problem Set 1("C")
# Time Spent: xx hours

def payInOne_BisectionSearch (balance,annualRate):
    #initialize variables
    initialBalance = balance
    monthlyRate = annualRate/12
    minMonthly = balance/12
    maxMonthly = (balance * (1 + monthlyRate ** 12 )/12
    monthlyPayment = (minMonthly + maxMonthly)/2
    numMonths = 1
    #define function to check balance after 12 months       
    def balanceAfterYear (balance, monthlyRate, monthlyPayment):
        for numMonths in range (1,13):
            interest = balance * monthlyRate
            balance += interest - monthlyPayment
            if balance <= 0:
                break
        return [balance, numMonths]
    resultList = balanceAfterYear(initialBalance, monthlyRate, monthlyPayment)
    print resultList[0],resultList[1]


payInOne_BisectionSearch (input("Enter the outstanding balance"),input("Enter annual rate as a decimal"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a closing bracket in the previous line.

```
maxMonthly = (balance * (1 + monthlyRate ** 12 )/12
```

Comment: Oh my gosh so embarrassing. Thank you.